# Verticall equidistant objects starting from the center

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, vertical-alignment

Is there a simple way of vertically placing rows of buttons equidistant from the (vertical) center in a div? What I mean by this is that the bottom of the upper button should be at, say, 40%, while the top of the lower button should be at 60%.

I am using bootstrap, and need some flexibility regarding how many buttons I will have in each "row".

Any help is highly appreciated.

I tried to produce a MWE here

```
.container {
  background-color: lightgray;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.btn {
  background-color: #722F37;
  display: block;
  font-size: 24px;
}

<div style="height:300px;" class="container">
 <button type="button" class="btn">
   Button 1
 </button>
 <button type="button" class="btn">
   Button 2
 </button>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/16kqbd0u/1/

Comment: you mean justify-content: center; no gaps?

Comment: Your fiddle seems to place the buttons at even distance from center

Comment: @ITgoldman: Yes, it does. But I cannot control the distance from the center, can I?

Comment: You can use padding for the container div that will allow you to control the distances instead of flex. just make sure first button it `top:0` and lower button is `bottom:0` absolutely positioned inside the relative div

Comment: Thank you, that's the way I settled for now. However, it does not allow me to have more than two button-rows and is also not ideal.